# thread.lib.php 1.1.4 Exception

Tags: php, multithreading, exception

I am trying to use the thread.lib.php library downloaded from http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpthreadlib/.

I used the following example code, provided in the docs:

```
<?php
require_once('thread.lib.php');

$child = new Thread('childMain');
$child->send('Hello');
$message = $child->recv();
$child->send('time to terminate');
echo "Child thread said '$message' \n";
exit;

function childMain(ThreadHandle $parentHandle)
{
  $message = $parentHandle->recv();
  $parentHandle->send("$message yourself");
  $parentHandle->recv();
  exit;
}
?>
```

I am getting a

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
>   'Exception' with message 'Error
>   communicating with child.'

error

> on line 429

Is this a known bug, or how would I make this example work?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Those Thread libraries in PHP are always workarounds. This one might fail for two reasons. It uses `exec("php -r ..")` which might contain the wrong binary name, or not run at all, so it won't create actual child processes. Secondly it tries to set up a listening socket for inter-process communication; which might be blocked for php scripts running below Apache. Concrete reason is hard to tell. This calls for debugging. Or try another (pcntl-based) thread emulation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't see any calls to exec in the code though... I also tested the called socket functions with `function_exists()`. The error seems to lie in the Thread launch method...

Comment: The exec call is `proc_open` in line 395.

Comment: `proc_open` works too according to my test: `<?php

if( ! function_exists('proc_open')) {
 die('OH NO');
}`

Comment: Function_exists only checks for the existence of a function. I'm sure `exec("missing_command")` will fail nevertheless. And a mod_jail / firewall setting can block socket listeners.